# delete % symbol from a text file

Tags: perl

I am trying to delete some content which is starting with % symbol. the input will be like this.

```
%abc
%bbc
```

I have writtent the script like below:

```
my $lineno=1;

while ($chapline =~ m/\%(.*?)$/msg)
    {
    $chapline =~ s/\%(.*?)$/&del;/g;
    }
$chapline =~ s/&del;//g;
```

but it is extracting the whole file from the first % symbol

pl. help in this regards

i used which i got answer from the below. but i am getting more spaces, and i am unable to remove those spaces

Comment: Are you trying to delete the entire line or just the percent sign? What's up with inserting and removing the &del; string?

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to delete lines that begin with a percent sign, simply do

```
perl -ne 'print unless /^%/' input > output
```

You can use a regex, but there really is no point, if all you are trying to do is print nothing.

I have no idea why you insert and remove the &del; string, but it is completely redundant.

You can use the in-place edit switch to edit the file, which would be

```
perl -i -ne ' ... ' input
```

Or with backup

```
perl -i.bak -ne ' ... ' input
```

Most of the times, I prefer shell redirection because it is safer.

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;

my $text = <<YOURTEXT;
%abc
%bbc
ccc
YOURTEXT

$text =~ s/\%(?:.*?\n)//xmg; # \r\n or \n depends on OS
print $text;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
ccc
```

Comment: can you tell me what is x in the replacement?

Comment: After using this there are more extra lines, but i tries with replacement. it is not working. can anybody help me

Comment: @vara Yes, I have answered it. Not sure why you are ignoring my answer.